# php project, file with non english name has blank name when downloaded

Tags: php, html, apache, utf-8, character-encoding

My php project is about showing files and directories in a list and the user can browse among the files-directories, search for a file by it's name and other. My problem is that if i search for a file it finds it(doesn't matter if it's name is english or greek) but if the file i choose to download isn't in english it's name will be blank. For example if it's name is "σουβλάκι.php" and i choose to download it the fill i will download will be named ".php". I believe it has to do with utf-8 but i can't figure it out. Any ideas will be really handfull.
In case it helps this is my download.php code:

```
<?php
setlocale (LC_ALL, "el_GR.UTF-8");
$file = $_GET["file"];
if (mb_detect_encoding($file)=="ISO-8859-1"){
$file = utf8_encode("$file");   
}
if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename($file)));
// header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
?>
```

and this is my index.php

```
<?php

    define("SUBFOLDER","http://192.168.1.3/webserver");
    define("ROOT","/var/www/webserver");
?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/myCSSfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>images/dit.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/search.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/button.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>css/button2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>js/resolutionfinder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>js/changeInputValue.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SUBFOLDER."/"; ?>js/ajaxcalls.js"></script>





<body onload='ShowDivInCenter();' onresize='ShowDivInCenter();'>
    <div class="cont">
        <div id="main">
            <?php
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                if ($_GET['action']=="view"){
                   include_once("foldercontents.php");
                }
                else if ($_GET['action']=="downloadZip"){
                    include_once("downloadZip.php");
                }
                else if ($_GET['action']=="downloadfile"){
                    include_once("download.php");
                }
                else {
                    include_once("foldercontents.php");
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: did you try `utf8_encode()` the filename?

Comment: I added this in my download.php at line 3. I also read somewhere that i shouldn't use the <meta charset="utf-8"> on index.php so i deleted it too. The outcome is the same though.

Comment: Oh I just saw you are using `basename()` if you need to use that than you have to set locale before you use `basename()` in your case I would setlocal() at start of the file like this `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'greek');` or maybe `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'gr_GR.UTF8');`

Comment: Firstly thnx for your time! I tried using setlocale also saw some examples about greek but didn't help. If you got any other ideas they're very welcomed.

Comment: Ι was using the wrong locale. I used the correct one and know it doesn't show .php as it's name, it shows %CE%BF%85 and more %something.php.

Comment: Thank you so much without setlocale i wouldn't find it. :)

Comment: Your welcome! I'm glad I was able to help you.

Comment: You should be aware that your code allows to download *any* file.

Answer (score 0):

First i added setlocale() as Laci K said on download.php and when i downloaded the non-english named file the name wasn't blank.php but it was %AC%BC%58%..more%something.php . Then i changed urlencode(basename($file))); to just basename($file); and now it works correctly. I also deleted the first if because it wasn't needed.
This is the before:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET["file"];
if (mb_detect_encoding($file)=="ISO-8859-1"){
$file = utf8_encode("$file");   
}
if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename($file)));
// header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
?>
```

and this is the correct one:

```
<?php
setlocale (LC_ALL, "el_GR.UTF-8");
$file = $_GET["file"];
if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
?>
```